# How to add Unique item to array in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My movie app has a favourite movies page and you can add movies to your favourite page by clicking on the like button on the movie itself, and I don't want to add the same movie over and over i tried this in my redux reducer:

```
const initialState = {
 favouriteMovies: []
}

const favMoviesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  
  switch (action.type) { 

    case actionTypes.GET_FAV_MOVIES:

      if (state.favouritesMovies.indexOf(action.favMovie === -1)) {
        return {
          favouritesMovies: [...state.favouritesMovies, action.favMovie],
          // note: action.favMovie is an object 
        };
      }

      return state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

but it didn't work so any advice please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TLDR

> There is some typo in `indexOf`

#### Answer

Yours code is that

```js
if (state.favouritesMovies.indexOf(action.favMovie === -1))
```

But, as far as i know, it' right usage of `indexOf` I guess it is typo.

```
if (state.favouritesMovies.indexOf(action.favMovie) === -1)
```

Comment: oh man I feel embarrassed lol, thank you so much tho

Comment: Good luck to you 

Answer (score 2):

As @Stark wrote, looks like you if statement isnt right.

Instead of indexOf, you also can check if a value exists inside an array with includes:

```
if (!state.favouritesMovies.includes(action.favMovie))
```

you can check more about it here: [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)